# vb.net, how to open a folder that contains a comma in it's path

Tags: vb.net

how to open a folder that contains a comma in it's path like:

```
Shell("explorer.exe \\server\path to, folder", vbHide) 
or 
Shell("cmd /c start \\server\path to, folder", vbHide)
```

thank You,

Answer (score 2):

The secret is to put quotes around the path, in Vb.Net, to do this you use a double quote:

```
Shell("explorer.exe ""\\server\path to, folder""", vbHide) 
or 
Shell("cmd /c start ""\\server\path to, folder""", vbHide)
```

you can also use the Process Class to start your process:

```
Process.Start("explorer", """\\server\path to, folder""")
```

Comment: this code is not working. I tried both of them and neither "shell" not "Process.Start" is able to open network location with comma in the path.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?  Can you navigate to the folder correctly in Explorer?  I just wrote a 1 line test app that has no problem with this on a network share (I originally tested with a local folder).

Comment: If I run a command line and then type: explorer.exe "\\server\path to, folder" - it is ok. If I run it from simple test app using Shell(...) nothing happens and there is no error. If I run it from test up using Process.Start(...) I get error: A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Comment: It could be a permission problem, have you tried a testapp that does the same, but without a comma in the path?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it was ok. Permisiion are ok. Right now I'm using some kind of workaround - from my app I'm running a batch file located on \\server\folder\start.cmd which has only one line of code: explorer "\\server\path to, folder"

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in VBA (Excel):

```
Dim ExplorerDirectoryName as String

ExplorerDirectoryName = "C:\Cats, Dogs and other animals"

Shell "C:\Windows\explorer.exe /e, " & Chr(34) & ExplorerDirectoryName & Chr(34), vbMaximizedFocus
```

Of course the directory 'C:\Cats, Dogs and other animals' should exist for this to work.